# Apache Tiles If/Else

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tiles2

I am wondering if it's possible to have an if/else with Apache Tiles 2 (or JSTL that references a Tiles attribute, that would work to). Basically, I want this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<div>
    <!-- Some stuff here -->
</div>
<tiles:if condition="showSecondDiv == 'true'">
    <div>
        <!-- Some second stuff here -->
    </div>
</tiles:if>
```

There is `<put-attribute name="showSecondDiv" value="true" type="string" />` in the Tiles XML. The motivation is that I want to reuse this JSP in a number of places, some that want to show both divs, others that only want to show one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USING JSTL
example:

```
     <c:if test="${!empty tilesAdditionalTitle}">
       <fmt:param value="${requestScope[tilesAdditionalTitle]}"  />
     </c:if>
```

Comment: Will that reference the attribute declared in my Tiles XML?

Comment: tilesAdditionalTitle this is the name of attribute

Comment: Ok, and what is the `requestScope[]` part?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tag importAttribute` for [if/else](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/importAttribute.html) condition.

layout.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/view/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/view/footer.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="sidebar" value="/WEB-INF/view/sidebar.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="showSideBar" value="Y" />
    </definition>   
</tiles-definitions>
```

template.jsp

```
<body>
    <t:importAttribute name="showSideBar"/>

    <t:insertAttribute name="header"/><br/>

    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
        <div class="uk-grid">

            <c:if test="${showSideBar == 'Y'}">
                <div class="uk-width-1-3">
                    <t:insertAttribute name="sidebar"/>
                </div>
            </c:if>

            <div class="${showSideBar == 'Y' ? 'uk-width-2-3' : 'uk-width-1-1'}">
                <t:insertAttribute name="body"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/view/common/loading.jsp"%>

    <t:insertAttribute name="footer"/>

</body>
```

If you do not want to show, then set `<put-attribute name="showSideBar" value=""/>` in the `layout.xml` file.